# Transfer data from aprs server to symfony database

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to connect symfony to an "aprs-is" server.

My data are received by the "aprs" server and i would like to insert them in the database i have created in the doctrine of symfony. My entities are ready but i can't figure out how to do that.

I can make an up-link on "aprs" server to redirect the data but i don't know how to architect all that link on both side.

Here is the link of aprs-is server archi: http://he.fi/aprsc/

The informations about the aprs uplink:
    $ sudo netstat -anp|grep aprsc

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.5.56:50002      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21864/aprsc         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10151         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21864/aprsc         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10151         127.0.0.1:46962         ESTABLISHED 21864/aprsc         
tcp        0      0 192.168.5.56:50002      192.168.5.54:34070      ESTABLISHED 21864/aprsc         
tcp6       0      0 :::50002                :::*                    LISTEN      21864/aprsc         
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      865809   21864/aprsc          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      864810   21864/aprsc          
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTE      864811   21864/aprsc
```

The information about apache listener
    $ sudo netstat -anp|grep apache2

```
tcp6       0      0 :::10150                :::*                    LISTEN      21582/apache2
```

The log connection on aprs:

```
2018/07/31 14:32:49.091674 aprsc[21864:7f5c008b1700] INFO: HTTP thread ready.
2018/07/31 14:32:49.091682 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] INFO: Uplink: 1 uplinks configured, 0 are connected, need to pick new
2018/07/31 14:32:49.091688 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] DEBUG: Uplink: trying Http (127.0.0.1:10150)
2018/07/31 14:32:49.091755 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] INFO: Uplink Http: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:10150 (127.0.0.1:10150) [link 0, addr 1/1]
2018/07/31 14:32:49.091832 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] DEBUG: Uplink Http: poll after connect returned 1, revents 4
2018/07/31 14:32:49.091840 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] DEBUG: Uplink Http: successful connect
2018/07/31 14:32:49.091858 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] INFO: Uplink Http: 127.0.0.1:10150: Connection established on fd 13 using source address 127.0.0.1:58630
2018/07/31 14:32:49.091865 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] DEBUG: pass_client_to_worker: client on fd 13 to thread 0 with 0 users
2018/07/31 14:32:49.091870 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] INFO: status: setting error flag no_uplink ttl 3600
2018/07/31 14:32:49.121688 aprsc[21864:7f5c00890700] DEBUG: collect_new_clients(worker 0): closing all existing peergroup peers
2018/07/31 14:32:49.121776 aprsc[21864:7f5c00890700] DEBUG: collect_new_clients(worker 0): added fd 13 to polling list, xfd 0x7f5c00a02000    
2018/07/31 14:32:49.121795 aprsc[21864:7f5c00890700] DEBUG: Worker 0 accepted 1 new clients, 1 new connections, now total 1 clients
2018/07/31 14:32:50.989005 aprsc[21864:7f5c00890700] INFO: 127.0.0.1:10150: Uplink server software: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
2018/07/31 14:32:50.989070 aprsc[21864:7f5c00890700] ERROR: 127.0.0.1:10150: Uplink's welcome message is not recognized: no # in beginning
2018/07/31 14:32:50.989098 aprsc[21864:7f5c00890700] INFO: Uplink TCP 127.0.0.1:10150 (Http) closed after 2 s: Uplink server protocol error, tx/rx 70/483 bytes 0/0 pkts, dropped 0, fd 13, worker 0
2018/07/31 14:32:50.989228 aprsc[21864:7f5c00890700] INFO: 127.0.0.1:10150: Uplink [0] has been closed: Uplink server protocol error
2018/07/31 14:32:50.989255 aprsc[21864:7f5c00890700] DEBUG: found the link to disconnect    
2018/07/31 14:32:53.096709 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] INFO: Uplink: 1 uplinks configured, 0 are connected, need to pick new
2018/07/31 14:32:53.096795 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] DEBUG: Uplink: trying Http (127.0.0.1:10150)
2018/07/31 14:32:53.096970 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] INFO: Uplink Http: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:10150 (127.0.0.1:10150) [link 0, addr 1/1]
2018/07/31 14:32:53.097139 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] DEBUG: Uplink Http: poll after connect returned 1, revents 4
2018/07/31 14:32:53.097177 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] DEBUG: Uplink Http: successful connect
2018/07/31 14:32:53.097275 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] INFO: Uplink Http: 127.0.0.1:10150: Connection established on fd 13 using source address 127.0.0.1:58632
2018/07/31 14:32:53.097305 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] DEBUG: pass_client_to_worker: client on fd 13 to thread 0 with 0 users
2018/07/31 14:32:53.097324 aprsc[21864:7f5bfd55f700] INFO: status: setting error flag no_uplink ttl 3600
2018/07/31 14:32:53.126840 aprsc[21864:7f5c00890700] DEBUG: collect_new_clients(worker 0): added fd 13 to polling list, xfd 0x7f5c00a02030
2018/07/31 14:32:53.126950 aprsc[21864:7f5c00890700] DEBUG: Worker 0 accepted 1 new clients, 1 new connections, now total 1 clients
2018/07/31 14:32:53.663743 aprsc[21864:7f5c008b1700] DEBUG: http status [127.0.0.1] request /status.json
2018/07/31 14:32:53.664754 aprsc[21864:7f5c008b1700] DEBUG: http_compress_gzip: compressed 7656 bytes to 1743 bytes: 22.8 %
2018/07/31 14:32:54.994428 aprsc[21864:7f5c00890700] INFO: 127.0.0.1:10150: Uplink server software: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

$ sudo service aprsc status
● aprsc.service - LSB: start and stop aprsc

Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/aprsc; generated; vendor preset: enabled)

```
Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-07-31 16:32:48 CEST; 20min ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 21831 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/aprsc stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 21844 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/aprsc start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Tasks: 8 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/aprsc.service
       └─21864 /opt/aprsc/sbin/aprsc -u aprsc -t /opt/aprsc -f test -e             debug -o file -r logs -c /etc/aprsc.conf

systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop aprsc...
aprsc[21844]:  * Preparing chroot for APRS-IS server: aprsc chroot
aprsc[21844]:    ...done.
aprsc[21844]:  *   Checking configuration 'aprsc'
aprsc[21844]:  * Starting APRS-IS server: aprsc
aprsc[21844]:  *   Starting 'aprsc'
aprsc[21844]:    ...done.
systemd[1]: Started LSB: start and stop aprsc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have progressed a little on that subject:

What's happening is the format sent from apache to aprs-is as response is badly interpreted by aprs. The apache server send a response with a header configured in apache2.conf: 
ServerTokens will return HTTP/1.1 with the version of apache after that ( the verbose depending on the option next to Servertoken )

But i can't figure out how change the value "HTTP/1.1" by "#APRS"

I've tried to change it in mod_header.c but the only file i have found is mod_header.so  ...